# Is It Possible To Alter a Facebook Wall Post?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have recently added support to post to a user's wall in my iPhone Application. However, I was wondering if it's possible to alter the text in a wall post after it has been posted. When I perform the post, I get a response from the server with the post id but it doesn't look like I can make modifications with it. It looks like the only way to do this is to delete the old post and create a new one. Is that correct?

Comment: It's not unusual. It prevents the case where you post something like "I am gonna donate to charity!" Then when people start posting back "Great idea!", "Me too!", etc you go back and change your original post to "I am going to throw cold water on a homeless guy."

Comment: @Josh Einstein: hehe... Official facebook information (from some article) is - to get more performance ;-)

Comment: Haha, yea I figured Facebook wanted to prevent this kind of activity but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible either from UI or API.